# Software and data dependencies graph tools

Tags: graph, dependencies

I'm looking for a good tool to represent software and/or data dependencies. Something like an application/job database with link between them and a graphic browsing capabilities.

The main reason is to answer the basic question: if I modifiy this application what else do I have to modify or test ?

I don't need an automated depencies analysis as I would like to use it with a lot of differents technologies. All information will be inserted manually.

Thanks for your ideas and experience sharing....

Answer (score 0):

You don't precise which platform your code base target, but for the .NET platform (C#, VB.NET, F#...) you can try the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) that proposes some advanced dependencies capabilities through [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx),
 [dependency structure matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) and [LINQ querying of code dependencies](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features#Dependencies). These features make it easy to do **impact analysis** before refactoring (similar to what you wrote: *if I modify this application what else do I have to modify or test ?*)